# CMake: What is the difference between `include_directories` versus `target_link_libraries`

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building a moderately sized C++ library and have cobbled together my `CMakeLists.txt` file from a bunch of different examples, etc. I was trying to understand the difference between `include_directories` versus the `target_link_libraries` instructions.

I list some of my code below, but just wanted to preface with a comment. I use the `Boost` library to build some of my code. So I have an instruction to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})` to include the Boost source directories in the build process. So I assume that Cmake will include these Boost Source files when building any executable--without any additional explicit instruction.

But later I have a `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( gd_validator ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )` when building an executable. So that suggests that I need to not only include the Boost directory, but then also explicitly link it with the executable.

So I was not sure if I actually needed both steps, or if I just needed the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` instruction and that was it.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(XXX) 
find_package(Boost 1.58.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem program_options chrono timer date_time REQUIRED)
if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "NOTICE: This demo requires Boost and will not be compiled.")
endif()
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

file(GLOB lib_SRC RELATIVE "lib/" "*.h" "*.cpp")
file(GLOB test_SRC RELATIVE "tests/" "*.h" "*.cpp")

# need to fix the instruction below to reference library
set(SOURCE_FILES ${lib_SRC} tests/testComplexCreator.cpp tests/testDataFormatter.cpp tests/testComplexAnalysis.cpp tests/testFascadeClass.cpp)
add_library(libXXX SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})    
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp random_mat_vector_generator.h random_mat_vector_generator.cpp)
add_executable(gd_validator gudhi_validator.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( gd_validator ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you need both.

`include_directories` will tell to the compiler where to look for the header files, in this case, the header files for the boost library.

`target_link_libraries` will tell to the linker which libraries you want to link against your executable.

While headers will provide (most of the time) just the interface to access the library, the library itself is precompiled and linked to your application.

Comment: Okay right. So as I understand what what you are saying, the `target_link_libraries` will precompile the headers/source of the target library and then link that against my application. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually the library is already precompiled. So the compiler will look for uses of the library in your code and just call it (shared libs) or replace the use with the actual library code (static libs). The whole point of using libraries is to avoid unnecessary compilations. 

You'll not need to add ``target_link_libraries`` only if the library is header-only

Comment: Okay, that is great. Yeah, that is what I was wondering about. Thanks so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

`include_directories` specifies the directories to be searched for included files (headers). `target_link_libraries` specifies the libraries to be linked to your target (executable or library).
Two completely​ different things.

Comment: Yeah, so this is what I was wondering about. So does `target_link_libraries` refer to only already compiled libraries? Usually I point to a directory with all of the Boost header and source files, and then the compiler will build against those files. So do I only need to `target_link_libraries` if I am pointing to a compiled library?

Comment: `target_link_libraries` does a whole lot more than linking. For example, it finds include directories.

Comment: Include files are used during compilation. Libraries are linked later. What's the confusion? You need to point the compiler at where to find includes. You also need to point the linker at libraries to link. These are completely different things and depending on what you want to do you need to do one or the other or both.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. See that is why I was asking. If `target_link_libraries` will find the include directories, then do I need a separate instruction for the `include_directories`? Or, does `target_link_libraries` rely on the folders identified by the `include_directories` instruction?

Comment: @krishnab It depends how the library that is being "linked" is defined, but if done properly, `target_link_libraries` would also get you the headers exported by that library. It is a badly named function.